# Is there a way to remove the sort after an SWT Table is sorted?

Tags: java, swt, tableviewer

I have a `Table` and `TableViewer` that are set up to take a `ViewerComparator`:

```
this.viewer.setComparator( this.comparator );
```

Now I am looking at my table. I click on a column header. The table sorts on that row. I click on that column header again and it sorts in the other direction. I click on a different column header and the sorting switches to the new column. This works beautifully.

My question is if there is a way to remove the sorting. This would mean getting rid of the sort arrow on top of the column header that I clicked, the gray background on the sorted column's elements would disappear, and the data would go back into its original order. I am open to adding some sort of button somewhere to start this command.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Table`s sort indicator and the comparator used by the `TableViewer` are actually independent.

To remove the sort indicator, call `table.setSortDirection( SWT.NONE )`. To remove the comparator, call `viewer.setComparator( null )`.

You could let the user switch through `UP`, `DOWN`, `NONE` when the column header is selected or provide an extra UI element to reset the sorting.

Comment: I did this and it worked great! Thanks for the idea.